# Resource Groups can't be deleted due to Permission issues

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

Certain Resource Groups have been created automatically upon the creation of other services

And even though I have the Contributor permission I still cannot delete a resource group

Note: I can delete any other service

Error:

```
Delete resource group X managedEnvironment-Labs-... Failed to delete resource group managedEnvironment_FunctionApps_c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30: The client 'example@gmail.com' with object id '7435434-cb77-4521-gf65-3443gf45t43' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/de... on scope 7subscriptions/4d81cdff-75ea-4082-a6ed-434ffb43gvfd43/resourceGroups/managedEnvironment-Labs-9179_FunctionApps_c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30'; however, the access is denied because of the deny assignment with name 'c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30' and Id 'c8a66b0741839de8c6e00f30' at scope 7subscriptions/4d81cdff-75ea-4082-a6ed-434ffb43gvfd43/resourceGroups/managedEnvironment_FunctionApps_c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30'. (Code: DenyAssignmentAuthorizationFailed)
```

I have managed to delete another resource group - however this one in specific I can't delete.

Additional Note: this resource group has no deployments in it and it doesn't contain any service.

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1460841/how-to-delete-a-rg-that-has-a-deny-assignment-cant

Answer (score 0):

Despite having the necessary permissions on your account, the action is being denied due to a "deny assignment" in Azure. A deny assignment is a specific type of Azure policy that explicitly denies certain actions regardless of any granted permissions.

In this case, this deny assignment is identified by the name 'c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30' and ID 'c8a66b0741839de8c6e00f30' and is applied at the scope of the resource group you are trying to delete (managedEnvironment_FunctionApps_c8a6-6b07-4183-9de8c6e00f30).

You need to check why the deny assignment was applied to this resource group. It might be protecting critical resources from being deleted or altered.